# How to do same function on every file in a folder in R?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

So I have a folder of identically formatted csv's . Let's call the folder "Folder" and the csv's:

- test1.csv
- test2.csv
- test3.csv
- ......

Each csv is formatted as follows

```
ID   date        hours  info
001  01/01/2019  8      xxxx
002  01/01/2019  22     xxxx
003  01/02/2019  4      xxxx
004  01/02/2019  5      xxxx
```

So the following works if I want one to work but how could I run and combine across all files in the folder?

```
totals <- df %>%
            group_by(date) %>%
            summarize(hour_sum = sum(hours)
```

So basically I want to have a dataframe which has every date in all files and the sum of the hours from ALL files.

So if `01/02/2019` appears in 3 files, I want the sum of hours for every occurence of that date in one df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to use the whole `tidyverse` set of packages, `purrr` gives you `map_dfr`, which returns a single dataframe by rbinding each dataset you read in. More info about it [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html).

The code would look something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

list.files(path = "path_to_data", full.names = TRUE) %>%
  map_dfr(read.csv) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarize(hour_sum = sum(hours))
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, if you use `map_dfr(read.csv, .id = "filename")` you get a column called "filename" with the original filename, right?

Comment: Yeah,  `.id` will create a column named 'filename' and filled with the "name" of each element in the list. The cleanest solution I have seen is `list.files('path') %>% set_names() %>%  map_dfr(read.csv, .id = 'filename')`

Comment: `set_names()` [from](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.5/topics/set_names)  the `purrr` package.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the code below

```
aggregate(
  hours ~ date,
  do.call(rbind, c(lapply(list.files(pattern = "test\\d+\\.csv"), read.csv), make.row.names = FALSE)),
  sum
)
```